# Modify a CSS class depending on Angular condition

Tags: css, angular

This div block displays a list inside of a square with a specific height

div1 blueSquare
div2 for
div3 if

My blueSquare Div is a wrap for a list and it's set as a none display.

I need the blueSquare div to be shown after the condition is fulfilled, otherwise, remain invisible

By the way, the order of the divs can not be modified

Thank you!!

I tried to set the class as none display and then after the condition run a script to set it as a block and I also tried `ngClass`.
I believe any of these would work but I am having a hard time

```html
<div  class="event if">
 <div *ngFor="let course of courseList| async|courseSections:courseNO; let index = index">
    <div   *ngIf="verifyThursday(course) && verifyTime(course) " >

            {{ course.TITLE }}
            {{ course.ROOM }
```

```
.event {
    padding: 0.2rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 40px;    
    display: none;
}
```

Should display the square ONLY if there are elements in the list

Comment: What is the condition to display the blueSquare? Can't you use *ngIf="" and put the condition there?

Comment: The condition would be if course.DAY==Thursday && course.START= 800

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="event double" [ngClass]="fullfilled ? 'd-block' : 'd-none'">
...
</div>
```

`d-block` & `d-none` come from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

In your component class, declare a boolean property and update it's value using your logic:

```
fulfilled: boolean;

updateFulfillment() {
  this.fulfilled = course.DAY === 'Thursday' && course.START === '800' ? true : false;
}
```

Afer that, a couple of ways you could do it using property binding in your template:

1. Use *ngIf to show/hide an element - this removes the element from the DOM completely:

```html
<div *ngIf="fulfilled">...</div>
```

2. Using style binding - the element is in the DOM, but not displayed:

```html
<div [style.display]="fulfilled ? 'block': 'none'>...</div>
```

3. If you have a pre-made class for showing/hiding, use [ngClass]:

```html
<div [ngClass]="fulfilled ? 'class-to-show': 'class-to-hide'>...</div>
```

In the third option, you can also specify `null` if you don't have a class for hidden state.